# Weak topology $\sigma(\mathscr X, \mathscr Y) $ on $\mathscr X$ ;$\mathscr X=\mathscr Y=\mathbb R^d $ is the usual euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider:

[image]

I am trying to make sense of the following example:

**Example**

> $\mathscr X = \mathscr Y =\mathbb R^d$, $\langle$
> $x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^dx_iy_i$. Then $\sigma(\mathscr X, \mathscr Y$
> $)=\sigma(\mathscr Y, \mathscr X)$ is the usual euclidean topology on
> $\mathbb R^d$

I am assuming that "minimal topology" is "initial topology", but I really couldn't find any reference to corroborate it. I read the wikipedia pages of weak topology and initial topology.

Assumption 4.1 seems to be stating than the family of functions $\{x \mapsto \langle x,y \rangle\}$are a "separating set" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_set) as I prove here:

Denoting for every $y \in \mathscr Y$, $b_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$

Let $x_1, x_2 \in  \mathscr X, x_1 \neq x_2$ Then $0 \neq x_1 -x_2 \in \mathscr X$. So by the assumption $ \exists y \in \mathscr Y$ s.t. $\langle x_1-x_2,y \rangle \neq 0 \iff \langle x_1,y \rangle \neq \langle x_2,y \rangle \iff b_y(x_1)\neq b_y(x_2)$.

Assumption 4.1 holds for this example, since if by absurd it does not, that is if $\exists x \neq 0$ s.t $\forall y \in \mathbb R^d$ $\sum_{i=1}^dx_iy_i=0$, then taking for i=1,...,d $y=y_i$, the vector with 1 in the i-th poistion, 0 everywhere else, it follows that x=0 contradicting the fact that  $ x \neq 0$, so the assumption holds. This is only good to be sure that $\sigma (\mathscr X, \mathscr Y)= \sigma(\mathscr Y, \mathscr X)= \sigma(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d)$ is Hausdorff, which is a necessary condition if it is in fact the usual euclidean topology.

**I am having trouble trying to prove that the topologies actually coincide**. I guess I have to prove the double inclusion, but haven't been able to do so. Here are my thoughts:

Let $\tau_e^d$ denote the usual euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^d$ and $\tau=\sigma(\mathscr X, \mathscr Y)$ the weak topology described above, which is a topology over $\mathscr X$.

I have to prove that $\tau =\tau_e^d $.

The initial topology $\tau$ is generated  by the set

$B :=\{b_y^{-1}(U),U \in \tau_e , y \in \mathscr Y\}$,  with $\tau_e$ the usual euclidean topology on the real line (provided I am allowed to chose it?).

I know $\tau_e^d$ is generated by the set $B_e^d=\{B_\epsilon(x)),\epsilon >0, x \in \mathscr X \}$ of open balls

Let $B_\epsilon(x)$ be an open ball center at $x$ with radius $\epsilon >0$.

I guess it is enought to prove that $B=B_e^d$, For that I need to prove $ B\subseteq B_e^d$ and  $ B_e^d \subseteq B$. I am stuck at this point.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: If you show the functions $\{x \rightarrow \langle x,y \rangle : y\in \mathcal{Y}\}$ are continuous in the usual topology, since the weak topology is the minimal topology s.t. this happens, you easily get one of the inclusions.

Comment: @Burno So minimal mean coarsest right? Then  the usual topology $\tau_e^d$would have to be finer that the weak topology $\tau$, that is$\tau \subseteq \tau_e^d$?

Comment: Also, to show the other inclusion, I wouldn't go by your way. $\tau_e \subseteq \tau$ is the same as saying that every open set in the euclidean topology is open in the weak topology. It is enough showing that every euclidean ball is a open set in the weak topology (since every open set in the euclidean topology is a union of balls). To do that, show that for every ball and every element in it, you can find a generator of the weak topology that is contained in the ball and contains that element.


And answering your comment: yes, that is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "minimal" topology means the smallest topology with respect to inclusion. It is generated by $\{f^{-1}(U):U\subset \mathbb{R}\text{ open},f\in \mathscr{Y}\}$, where $\mathscr{X}$ is a real vector space and $\mathscr{Y}$ is a collection of (norm-to-Euclidean) continuous, real-valued , linear functionals on $\mathscr{X}$. It can also be defined to be the intersection of all topologies $\tau$ such that each $f\in \mathscr{Y}$ is continuous when considered as a map from $(X,\tau)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Here, the *only* topology we consider on $\mathbb{R}$ when considered as the range of a $\mathscr{Y}$ functional is its usual Euclidean topology.

By minimality of $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$ and the fact that every $f\in \mathscr{Y}$ is norm continuous by assumption (that is, $f:(X, \|\cdot\|)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous), $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})\subset \tau_{\text{norm}}$.  To see it another way, for $f\in \mathscr{Y}$ and $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ open, $f^{-1}(U)$ is norm open by continuity, so the topology generated by such sets must stay within the norm topology.

We want to show that $\tau_{\text{norm}}\subset \sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$ when $\mathscr{X}=\mathscr{Y}=\mathbb{R}^d$ (this is actualy true for any finite dimensional TVS $\mathscr{X}$ where $\mathscr{Y}$ is its dual space). In order to show the desired inclusion, it is sufficient to show that $B_\mathscr{X}:=\{x\in \mathscr{X}:\|x\|<1\}$ is $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$-open (why?).  To that end, let $e_1, \ldots, e_d$ be the usual basis and let $$U=\bigcap_{i=1}^d e_i^{-1}((-1/d,1/d)).$$ Here, $e_i$ is considered as a function on $\mathscr{X}$ by the action $x\mapsto \langle e_i, x\rangle$.  This is a finite intersection of members of $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$.  It's contained in $B_\mathscr{X}$ (again, why?).

Comment: We can actually use $1/\sqrt{d}$ instead of $1/d$, and that's optimal, but that's not necessary for this problem.

Comment: To answer the second why:Let $x \in U $, then $x_i=\langle e_i,x \rangle \in (-1/d, 1/d) \implies x_i^2<1/d^2 \implies \sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2=||x||^2<1/d \implies ||x||<1$ so $x \in B_{\mathscr X}$. So this proves that $ U \subseteq B_{\mathscr X}$. Am I right?

Comment: For the first why I am not so sure. If V is a generic open set of the $\tau_{\text{norm}}$, I have to prove that it is also in the weak topology., how do I proceed?

Comment: You are correct for the second why. For the first, note that translations (functions of the form $y\mapsto x+y$) and scaling by a non-zero scalar (functions of the form $y\mapsto ry$) are both homeomorphisms of $(\mathscr{X},\tau)$ with itself, where $\tau$ is either the norm or $\sigma(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^d)$ topology. So a generic open ball can be scaled and translated to be the open unit ball at zero. Fit a weakly open set containing $0$ inside of it, then scale and translate back again. The scaled translated weakly open set will fit inside the generic ball.

Comment: I still don't see how to go from $B_{\mathscr X}$ being weakly open  to getting the inclusion $\tau_{\text{norm}}\subseteq \sigma (\mathscr X, \mathscr Y)$?I have to start with something in $\tau_{\text{norm}}$

Comment: If $B_\mathscr{X}$ is weakly open, then $B(x,r)$ (the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$) is weakly open by scaling and translating. If $U$ is norm open, for each $x\in U$, there exists $r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x)\subset U$. Each $B(x,r_x)$ contains a weak neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ (the second why + scaling and translating). Then $U=\cup_{x\in U} V_x$ is weakly open.

Comment: To prove the first inclusion $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})\subset \tau_{\text{norm}}$, isn't it sufficient the minimality to directly write this inclusion?. Why do i need to use that f is norm continuous? Otherwise I woud start like this: take a $V \in \sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y}) $, and then can I argue that it is enough to prove the inclusion for a set of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, because it is an element of the generating set by definition of initial topology?

Comment: It isn't sufficient to say "$\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})\subset \tau_{\text{norm}}$ by minimality", because $\sigma(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{Y})$ is minimal **in a certain collection of topologies**, and you have to state that $\tau_\text{norm}$ is in that collection.

Comment: OK, so this collection of topologies are those which make all possible functionals f continuous, correct? Then to check $\tau_{\text norm }$ is one of those , I observe that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a preimage of an open set $U$ via the norm continuous function $f$, so  $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_{\text norm }$.On the other hand  $f^{-1}(U) \in \sigma (\mathscr X, \mathscr Y)$ by definition of inital topology, and by minimalityI have the inclusion. This proves the inclusion for $f^{-1}(U) $ Since the generating set consists on these sets, then it is also proven for a genric open set V. Everything in order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148068/discussion-between-bangs-and-some-math-guy).